# Date format conflict

Tags: php, database, date

I have a field "joindate" in my table. It consists of datas with mixed format. (14-01-2015 and 14.01.2015) . I want to fetch datas from that table on the desc order of date. How can I do this ? The type of joindate is varchar.
I have tried in the following way;

Converted that string to date by using str_to_date . But still its not working.

```
    select * from employee where employeeid='14' order by str_to_date(joindate,'%d.%m.%Y') desc;
```

Comment: post your query here

Comment: But there are other format also there right

Comment: select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d-%Y') as date from employee where employeeid='14' order by date  desc;

Comment: i have tried with date_format. but no use

Comment: **FYI: As a best practice always save the date as one format. As I know MySQL use `-` for date with format of `YYYY-mm-dd`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```sql
select * from employee where employeeid='14' order by if(strcmp(str_to_date(datejoin,'%d.%m.%Y'),datejoin),datejoin,date_format(str_to_date(datejoin,'%d-%m-%Y'),'%d.%m.%Y')) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `date_format` its work for me

```
 select * from employee where employeeid='14' order by date_format(str_to_date(joindate,'%d-%m-%Y'), '%d.%m.%Y') desc;
```

Comment: it still gives output with mixed dates, not in desc order

Comment: you share your output if possible

Answer (score 0):

If the *joindates* are on database then you can just use

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeid = '14' ORDER BY joindate DESC
```

It's eather that or you should just get rid of those percent characters?